# foreach PHP y tabla HTML

Tags: php

Estoy programando en `PHP` y `MySQL` y quiero llenar una simple tabla `HTML` con una consulta. Tengo problemas con el `foreach`, este es mi código:

```
<table>
        <tr>
            <th>CODIGO</th>
            <th>DESCRIPCION</th>
            <th>GRUPO</th>
            <th>SECCION</th>
            <th>VIGENTE</th>
        </tr>
        <?php
        if (isset($_POST["btnBuscar"])) {
             $codigo = $_POST['txtCodigo'];
             $ser->codigoservicio = $codigo;
             $data = $sDriver->getByCodigo($codigo);
             //print_r($data);
            if(!empty($data)){
                    foreach ($data as $item) { ?>
                      <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $data->codigoservicio; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $data->descripcion; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $data->grupo; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $data->codigoseccion; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $data->vigente; ?></td>
                      </tr>     
        <?php       
            }
         ?>
        </table>
        <?php 
            }else{
                echo 'No hay resultados.';
            }
        }   
        ?>
```

esto me muestra los resultados pero pero los repite 5 veces cada uno, y si uso:

```
<td><?php echo $item->codigoservicio; ?></td>
```

obtengo el siguiente error:

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs...

```
print_r($data);
```

Me devuelve:

```
OaServicio Object ( 
                   [codigoservicio] => 12 
                   [grupo] => 3 
                   [descripcion] => prueba 
                   [codigoseccion] => 1 
                   [vigente] => 1 
                  )
```

¿Cómo puedo hacer?

Comment: Hola @daniel, que tal si descomentas el print_r($data), le agregar una etiqueta pre y nos lo muestras para ver como traes los datos, al final debes colocarlo asi: `echo "<pre>"; print_r($data); echo "</pre>";`

Comment: hola, me devuelve esto:  OaServicio Object
(
    [codigoservicio] => 12
    [grupo] => 3
    [descripcion] => prueba
    [codigoseccion] => 1
    [vigente] => 1
)

Comment: Los valores del ciclo están en $item, no en $data (http://php.net/manual/es/control-structures.foreach.php)

Comment: pero al usar $item me sale el error que puse arriba

Comment: Intenta usando `<tr>
    <td><?php echo $item ?></td>
    </tr> `

Comment: @daniel puedes también colocar lo que actualmente te esta regresando, veo que solo tienes 1 registro, no comentes solo actualiza y así lo vemos, porque se hacen muchos comments

Answer (score 5):

Te dejo el siguiente script, espero te sirva:

```
 if(!empty($data)){
 $tds = ""; //Inicmaos variable tds
 foreach ($data as $i=>$v) {  //Iteramos tu objeto
    $tds .= "<td>".$v."</td>"; // Extraemos solo el valor concatenandolo en la variable $tds.
 }
 echo "<tr>".$tds."</tr>"; // Imprimimos el resultado final
```

Comment: gracias , anduvo perfecto. Nunca lo habia hecho de esta forma, siempre lo hacia como puse en la publicacion inicial y no habia tenido problemas,gracias

Comment: @daniel Felicidades por el código. Ahora cada vez que alguna respuesta te haya sido útil, cual sea, debes elegirla como que sirva de referencia, de igual forma puedes agregarle puntos para que de igual forma sirva como referencia.

Answer (score 1):

En vista a lo que muestras no deberias usar un foreach ya que puedes acceder directamente a los elementos, puedes hacer lo siguiente y obtendras una sola fila:

```
<table>
<tr>
  <th>CODIGO</th>
  <th>DESCRIPCION</th>
  <th>GRUPO</th>
  <th>SECCION</th>
  <th>VIGENTE</th>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><?php echo $data->codigoservicio; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $data->descripcion; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $data->grupo; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $data->codigoseccion; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $data->vigente; ?></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Ahora si quieres usar el foreach puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
<table>
<tr>
  <th>CODIGO</th>
  <th>DESCRIPCION</th>
  <th>GRUPO</th>
  <th>SECCION</th>
  <th>VIGENTE</th>
</tr>
<tr>
  <?php foreach ($data as $item) { ?>
    <td><?php echo $item; ?></td>
  <?php } ?>
</tr>
</table>
```